# Javascript reduce keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm trying to figure out a problem where I need to find the product of all numbers in an array.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this keeps returning undefined.

I would love any suggestions on why my code is not working. Thank you!

```
function mutliplyAllElements(arr) {

  arr.reduce(function(x, y) {
    return x * y;
  });
}

mutliplyAllElements([2, 3, 100]);  // 600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting undefined because function `mutliplyAllElements` does not return anything. You have to `return` the value in the function.

```js
function mutliplyAllElements(arr) {
  let val = arr.reduce(function(x, y) {
    return x * y;
  });
  return val;
}

console.log(mutliplyAllElements([2, 3, 100]));
```

Or you can make it shorter as:

```js
function mutliplyAllElements(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((x, y) => x * y);
}

console.log( mutliplyAllElements([2, 3, 100]) );
```